# Why does the orthogonality of elements of a linearly independent system not matter when using the Ritz method?

Tags: functional-analysis

There is a functional $F[x]$. Using the Ritz method, an approximate optimization is required. According to the Ritz method, we choose a complete linearly independent system of functions $ \left\{ e_{k} \right\}_{k = 1}^{\infty} $ in some Hilbert space $H$ and every possible linear combination of first $n$ elements of $ \left\{ e_{k} \right\}_{k = 1}^{\infty} $: 
$$ x_{n} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} c_{k} e_{k}, \quad c_{k} \in \mathbb{R} .$$

It is clear that $x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots, x_{n}$ form a finite linear subspace in space $H$. Let's call it $X_{n}$.

Suppose that $ \left\{ e_{k} \right\}_{k = 1}^{\infty} $ is not orthogonal, then let's apply Gram–Schmidt process to the system and get new orthogonal system $ \left\{ e_{k}^{'} \right\}_{k = 1}^{\infty} $. Аs a result, in both cases, the $ x_{n} $is the same. Then it is logical to assume that $$ Lin\{ e_{1}, e_{2}, \dots, e_{n} \} = Lin\{ e_{1}^{'}, e_{2}^{'}, \dots, e_{n}^{'} \} = X_{n} .$$
 But how to prove that?

Comment: It is unclear what you are talking about. It would be better if you posted a concrete example.

Comment: It holds, because of the properties of the Gram-Schmidt process. By the way, I guess the name you mention is correctly '*Riesz*'.

Comment: @Berci Isn’t the method named after *Walther Ritz*?